# How to Focus on Errors in react-admin 4.x

Tags: react-admin

I've been porting a react-admin 3.19 project for a while now, and the only behavior left to implement on 4.x is to focus the first field that fails validation, in react-admin 3.19 that was achieved with something like:

```
import createDecorator from 'final-form-focus';
const focusOnErrors = createDecorator();
...
    <Edit>
      <SimpleForm
        decorators={[focusOnErrors]}>
```

But on 4.x final-form-focus was replaced with react-hook-form, which I found how to focus on the first field with errors, but I'm not sure how to implement that on react-admin or if it will work with react-admin, the code should be something like:

```
const {
  setFocus,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = Object.keys(errors).reduce(
      (field, a) => (errors[field] ? field : a),
      null,
    );

    if (firstError) {
      setFocus(firstError);
    }
  }, [errors, setFocus]);
```

How can I make react-admin focus on the first field that fails validation?

Comment: createDecorator looks to be coming from a library. is that library not working ? also, you can attach a ref to them and use the focus() method on it to focus directly without any 3rd party library

Comment: @innocent No, it's the old code on a previous version that was working, that library was replaced with react-hook-form.

Comment: yeah then you need to hook either the library and check if its working or go with the above suggestion and use `useRef`